# javascript object HTMLIFrameElement error

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i am trying to get the selected value from the iframe.

Here i have a i frame,in that i am entering the text.

When i select a part of text from iframe and click button that calls java script function,
i am getting the error in alert

```
[object HTMLIFrameElement]
```

how can i solve this?

JavaScript Function Code:

```
function popup(obj, code){
alert(obj);
alert(code);
wrapText(obj, '<+code+>', '</+code+>');
}
```

Comment: is not an error. It's the string representation of the object `obj`

Answer (score 0):

1. use *console.log()* instead of *alert()*
2. reload the page and check out the browser's console
3. click on `[object HTMLIFrameElement]`

Now you will see the content of the object and the properties you can access by `object.properties` syntax